# Most efficient fillet design given an envelope (for stress)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, stresses, finite-element-method, strength

If one has a specified allowed X length and Y height, into which a fillet can be placed to reduce stress concentrations, is there an equation which can be used to determine the optimal shape of the fillet?

I have looked into Baud Fillets and Thum-Bautz fillets, but I find that although these fillets work fantastically for a desired y height OR a desired x height, these don't work well when one has constraints on both of these dimensions. Furthermore, it seems scaling the fillet shape along the axis does not work well, in many cases ending up worse than a circular fillet.

If it is relevant, this is for fillets that are to be placed on the ID or OD of steps in tubing.

I know one option is various shape optimization algorithms, but I was hoping that there was some kind of out of the box solution that I could use to hopefully avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this area, but what you might do is constrain just x, see what the resulting FEA stress is, and compare that to just constraining y. That would at least get you the best out of those formulas.

Here is a good [fillet research paper](https://medsi.lbl.gov/SysIncludes/retrieve.php?url=https://medsi.lbl.gov/files/page_139/Session_3_High_Precision_Position_Mechanisms__Vibration_Stability/04-25_Investigation_of_optimised_notch_shapes_for_flexural_hinges_S.Zelenika_S.Henein_L.Myklebust.pdf) I skimmed. Looks like the grodzinski filet shape might be something to look into.

[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/264601337_fig3_Fig-3-Geometrical-construction-of-Grodzinski-profile) (might be a good paper but you have to buy it)
[image]

Comment: I have actually looked into this fillet design in the past. I actually found that it can be more efficient to have a chamfer with a fillet on the chamfer edge than this technique. Although, that does require extra playing around, and in many cases that might not be worthwhile for the marginal benefit that it allows.

Comment: Are you using FEA to evaluate? What software? Have you validated the model with real world tests? What sizes are we dealing with here? Has tool tolerance and surface quality been accounted for? Again, not an expert on this, but that might bring up some good discussion. Its important that you are solving the real problem and not just tricking the simulation. Posting some of your attempts and respective stress heat maps to your question would be helpful.

Comment: I have been using the FEA built within SolidWorks. I have not validated the model with real world tests, and no I have not been accounting for surface quality or tolerancing here, but for my case, with the quality of machining that I would be using, I do not believe these factors to be relevant. While I cannot share the parts that are used in this simulation, I can show images, which I have included [here](https://imgur.com/a/bj3mM). In terms of loading and FEA setup, the part is elastically supported on one end, sliced into sixteenths, and a force of about 38000 pounds is placed on the other

Comment: end, representing a total force of just over 600,000 pounds. In terms of the mesh, it is made more fine around the location of the fillet, and an image of that is shown in my above link.

Comment: In terms of tricking the simulation, I am not too concerned with this, as the procedure that I have used is how we analyze all of our parts, historically it has performed well, so I very much hope that it is at least somewhat accurate.

Comment: I understand better now with the images. I think the reason the fillet equations are not preforming in your design is because your final surfaces are parallel with no 90 degree surface required in between. Something like a population curve may give you better results. The interface to the larger section could be squared off to reduce the footprint; as it wont have a stress concentration as you have already shown.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function?wprov=sfla1

Comment: You might be right with the interface difference. That is something that I can look at comparing. Do you mind me asking for your logic with the logistic curve? I'm not sure that I agree that that will be a strong shape. Most of the other designs I have looked at, including the Baud fillet seem to have a longer more lead in compared to the logistic curve. Additionally, looking at the tenth page of [this paper](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lfm/papers/Castro-TAFM2016-DOI_10.1016_j.tafmec.2016.03.005.pdf) the diagrams seem to show a low stress concentration at the top of the shoulder of

Comment: the joint. Which seems to make sense logically. This leads me to question why a logistic curve would work well, as it seems to devote half of its height to a region that is of low importance in terms of stress.

Comment: The logic function is just an equation that can be used to transition between two parallel lines. Like i mentioned, you only have to use one side of it as the other side is not critical. (Just continue tangent at the inflection point.) The load vectors will follow a path similar to this equation, so even though you are disregarding that part of the curve to decrease your footprint, the path is still relevant. The important change is that the equation is aware of the other other parallel surface. You will have to change the function parameters to adjust the slope at the inflection point.

Comment: It will take some iteration and you may find a better function to represent, but having an equation that is aware of both parallel lines will be required for a general solution.